# What is the best search plugin for Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, lucene, grails-2.0, hibernate-search

There are two very powerful search plugins for Grails. The [Searchable Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) and the [Hibernate Search Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-search). Both are based on the Lucene search engine.

Which plugin is the best? Are there fields where one plugin is better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

The searchable plugin is stable but compass what it was built on is somewhat stalled in development.

I don't know much about the Hibernate Search Plugin.

There are two other options to look at there is Solr and a Solr plugin but the plugin needs some love for a while but the Solr project is fine.

Finally there is [elasticsearch](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) which is the *replacement* for compass.

Here is a presentation from GR8Eu wich goes over some items about grails search. http://gr8conf.eu/Presentations/Searching-for-the-Grail

Answer (score 1):

First you need to specify which kind of search you would like to achieve. I can think about "full text" search (search in every domain class, every property), full domain search (complex search ability for given domain class), lightweight search.

Lightweight search usually suitable for backend quick search with autocomplete is supported by [Quick Search Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-quick-search). It can search by simple datatypes (String, Number) in given domain class and even in its relationships.

I was using [Filterpane plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/filterpane) for full domain search which I can recommend. It is quite advanced it supports search by many data tapes (String, Numbers, Date, Joda Time, Enums, etc.). Moreover, relationship search and inheritance search is also supported.

I have no experience with "full text" search plugin but I think that Searchable Plugin would be good way to go...

Answer (score 0):

I know two plugins:

- Grails Hibernate Search plugin: which I just migrated to be Grails 3.1.x / Hibernate 5 compatible (see PR https://github.com/mathpere/grails-hibernate-search-plugin/pull/21)
- Grails Searchable plugin: which is great and full of features but not compatible with last Grails version.

so I would say that it depends on your Grails version.